# Windows 8 metro apps Switching between 2 cameras

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using MediaCapture class for camera view. But i have a problem that it supports only front camera of tablet, i want to switch between front and back camera by clicking a button.
How can i do it??

Comment: Are you on Developer preview build ?

Comment: yes i am on Developer preview build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sajid,

This example code from the Win8 Dev Center will show you how to enumerate through the camera devices connected to a current machine: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622

And here's another example which deals with DeviceEnumeration more specifically: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Device-Enumeration-Sample-a6e45169

Relevant code (from first link) :

```
private async void EnumerateWebcamsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            ShowStatusMessage("Enumerating Webcams...");
            m_devInfoCollection = null;

            EnumedDeviceList2.Items.Clear();

            m_devInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
            if (m_devInfoCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                ShowStatusMessage("No WebCams found.");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < m_devInfoCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    var devInfo = m_devInfoCollection[i];
                    EnumedDeviceList2.Items.Add(devInfo.Name);
                }
                EnumedDeviceList2.SelectedIndex = 0;
                ShowStatusMessage("Enumerating Webcams completed successfully.");
                btnStartDevice2.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ShowExceptionMessage(e);
        }
    }
```

edit: this code is taken from the AdvancedCapture.xaml.cs file from the first code sample I posted.